# How do I save an image, or text file for later use?

Tags: java, persistence

How do I save an image, or text file for later use?(writing and creating a file)

Comment: Open it, write to it, and close it? You need to be more specific; searching the web for "writing Java file" is replete with examples. Is something not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FileOutputStreams. Images should be written in binary mode.(DataOutput/InputStream)
Search engines provide you several matches like:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/java-write-to-file.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/java/writeText/index.html) tutorial for writing to files and this tutorial for [Java Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/serial.html). You can also use [Google](http://www.google.com.mt/) to find tutorials about what you need to do.